# How to structure, develop and test models in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm moving from Java development to Node.js, so far I have learned basics of Express.

Now I'm looking to learn how to structure, develop and test business logic and models in Node. I have found [this](http://forrst.com/posts/How_I_make_models_in_Node_js_using_Redis_as_dat-90W) short article helpful but I'm looking for more in depth tutorials and articles.

I'm trying to learn Node, so please do not suggest [web or full-stack] frameworks, however helper libraries are welcomed.

Comment: Are you at least open to using Nodeunit?

Comment: @Brad Thanks, sure it is not a framework, testing utilities are very important, I will study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally liked [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) as a testing framework. It has a lot of flexibility and community support behind it. I also appreciate that you can use whatever assertion library with it that you want (e.g. I like [should](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js)). The mocha site itself has some pretty good examples.

Here is a good step-by-step article of someone migrating tests over to mocha and should: https://brianstoner.com/blog/testing-in-nodejs-with-mocha/. I especially liked his example of testing HTTP requests.

FWIW here is a small personal project of mine where I've attempted to follow some best practices of code organization and testing (in particular take a peak at the grunt test targets): https://github.com/chmontgomery/Pongorithm. It's still very basic but I hope you get the idea. I followed the [kraken.js](http://krakenjs.com/) model of [code organization](http://krakenjs.com/#Structure).